# Error in creating relationship between multiple nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to cypher. I have created nodes and want to create a relationship between them, but it throws an  error

> Invalid input '': expected whitespace or pattern.

```
MATCH (a: HIX {name: ‘Hairy’}), 
(b:ROCK{name:’Rocky’}) ,
(c: Carey{name:’Alex Carey’}) ,
(d:Prince{name:' Edward Prince'})
CREATE (a)-[r: Head_of]->(b),(a)-[r: Head_of]->(c),
(a)-[r: Head_of]->(d)
RETURN a,b,c,d
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a wrong character for strings (`‘`) use either `` ` `` (backtick) or `"` (quotes). If you try the query in Neo4j browser it shows you exactly where the problem is:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input '‘': expected whitespace, comment or an expression (line 1, column 22 (offset: 21))
"MATCH (a: HIX {name: ‘Hairy’}), "
                      ^
```

Additionally you have multiple relationships named `r`, use unique names for these.

I would also recommend to format the code bit more cleanly, e.g.

```
MATCH (a:HIX {name: 'Hairy'}), 
  (b:ROCK {name:'Rocky'}),
  (c:Carey {name:'Alex Carey'}),
  (d:Prince {name:' Edward Prince'})
CREATE 
  (a)-[r0:Head_of]->(b),
  (a)-[r1:Head_of]->(c),
  (a)-[r2:Head_of]->(d)
RETURN a,b,c,d
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying . There was a mistake in the way I put the data . After I made the changes it worked. Thanks for your answer .